# "Depend just as much on"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> Moore and Noyce shared a vision, recognizing that success depended just as much on intellectual pizzazz as on Intel's ability to deliver a product.

What does this sentence mean? The part "depended just as much on .... as on..." is so confusing. I would be grateful if someone could clarify this part for me.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to EL&U. The sentence means "To succeed, Moore and Noyce needed two things: (1) intellectual pizzaz and (2) ability to deliver, and they knew that (1) was *just as important* to succeeding as (2)". In addition, it is implied that one might expect (or that the men's contemporaries expected) that (2) was obviously more important than (1), but these men knew otherwise, and this sentence sets out to dispel the misconception. Having said all that, you may prefer to ask this question on our sister stack, [ELL.SE].

Comment: Oh my, thank you very much for your explanation. And about the stack that you mentioned, is there any difference between this site and that site? Sorry, I'm new to this website.

Comment: No need to apologize! The other stack, ELL, is aimed at people learning English, who might trip up over constructions which wouldn't bother native speakers. This stack, ELU, is mostly populated by people who have English as a first language, and some people who study English professionally. That said, the question is perfectly fine here, and being a member of ELU in no way precludes you from being a member of ELL or vice-versa. I only suggested you ask over there because those guys have developed an knack for explaining weird aspects of English in a way that makes the language more accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should recognize that in the part you mentioned, the " as much as " structure is used. we use this structure when we want to say that something can have similar particular quality as something else. as an example we might say something like : " smoking is harmful to our bodies as much as eating fast-food OR smoking as much as eating fast-food is harmful to our bodies". so being harmful is that particular quality here and we are trying to say that smoking can be harmful to the same extend that fast-food is (harmful).

but sometimes we can integrate(which means connecting or joining) that quality in the structure to be more fluent in the way we want to talk about something. the same example here, instead of using the sentence above we could say " smoking is as much harmful to our bodies as eating fast food is. sounds even better.

now consider that some verbs are followed by some prepositions which are usually called "phrasal verbs" , like : " depend on , look at , talk about , rely on , etc. "  we can even join the prepositions of phrasal verbs in "as much as" structure. this applies to the sentence you are talking about. "...success DEPENDED just as much ON intellectual pizazz as on Intel's ability to deliver a product..."

hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you for your meticulous explanation. I'm really grateful. The problem is that I've misclicked the Vote Down function and I can't undo it (I use laptop), so sorry about that.

Comment: oh never mind. I'm glad it helped.